# Thymeleaf retrieving text from input with similar field name adding it to another separated by comma

Tags: java, spring-boot, thymeleaf

I'm asking for help because thymeleaf does somthing weird:
Here is my form:

```
<form action="#" th:action="@{/add-new-board}" method="post">

    <p>Board name: <input type="text" th:name="board" th:field="${board.name}" /></p>
    <p th:if="${#fields.hasErrors('board.name')}" th:errors="${board.name}">Name Error</p>

    <p>Section #1 name: <input type="text" th:name="section" th:field="${section.name}" /></p>
    <p th:if="${#fields.hasErrors('section.name')}" th:errors="${section.name}">Name Error</p>

    <p><input type="submit" value="Submit" /> <input type="reset" value="Reset" /></p>
</form>
```

Here is my controller:

```
@GetMapping(path = "/add-new-board")
public String addNewBoardForm(Model model) {
    model.addAttribute("board", new Board());
    model.addAttribute("section", new Section());
    return "fragments/forms/add-new-board";
}

@PostMapping(path = "/add-new-board")
public String addNewBoardSubmit(@Valid @ModelAttribute Board board,
                                @Valid @ModelAttribute Membership membership,
                                @Valid @ModelAttribute Section section,
                                @AuthenticationPrincipal UserDetailsImpl principal,
                                BindingResult result,
                                RedirectAttributes attributes) {
    if (result.hasErrors()) {
        attributes.addFlashAttribute("create_board_fail", "Check if you have all fields");
        return "fragments/forms/add-new-board";
    } else {
        board.setCreated_at(LocalDateTime.now());
        Slugify slug = new Slugify();
        board.setSlug(slug.parse(board.getName()));
        boardRepository.save(board);

        User user = userRepository.findByEmail(principal.getEmail()).get();
        membership.setMember_type(MemberType.MANAGER);
        membership.setBoardId(board);
        membership.setUserId(user);
        membershipRepository.save(membership);

        section.setBoard(board);
        section.setColor(ColorType.BLUE_BASIC);
        section.setOrdering(1);
        sectionRepository.save(section);

        attributes.addFlashAttribute("create_board_success", "You successfully added a new board!");
        return "redirect:/";
    }
```

So, my goal is to insert text from 1st input to "board" table to a column "name", and insert text from 2nd input to "section" table to a column "name". So this column titles are similar. Now when I run code, fill inputs and submit it, I'm getting to my database:

[database tables img](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ye59l.png)

Where "AAA" is what I wrote in 1st input, and "BBB" in 2nd

Answer (score 2):

This is happening because you are using `th:field` incorrectly.  `th:field` is designed to be used with a single `th:object` but right now you are using 2 different objects `board` and `section`.  When the HTML is rendered, both inputs probably have the same `name="name"` and when that is submitted, the values are concatenated together and you get the behavior you are seeing.

You should instead add Board and Section to a single object, and use that as your form.  For example, if you created a `BoardForm` object:

```
public class BoardForm {
  private Board board = new Board();
  private Section section = new Section();

  // Getters and setters...
}
```

added that to your model instead

```
model.addAttribute("form", new BoardForm());
```

then your html would look like this

```
<form action="#" th:action="@{/add-new-board}" th:object="${form} method="post">
    <p>Board name: <input type="text" th:name="board" th:field="*{board.name}" /></p>
    <p>Section #1 name: <input type="text" th:name="section" th:field="*{section.name}" /></p>
    <p><input type="submit" value="Submit" /> <input type="reset" value="Reset" /></p>
</form>
```