# Thymeleaf concatenates values of input fields where the attribute names of the objects are identical

Tags: java, html, spring, spring-mvc, thymeleaf

I am passing multiple objects from a Spring controller to the view. There I am filling data to the  passed objects with Thymeleaf. The problem is that the passed objects have similar attribut names. For example the invoiceRecipientDTO has a fname and the GuestDTO has also a fname. The problem now is: After submitting the form, all input fields having the same name are getting concatenated by a comma.

Example:
Invoicerecipient --> fname: Test
Guest --> fname: XYZ

after submitting the form both values will be concateneted by a comma, so the attribute fname of GuestDTO and InvoiceRecipientDTO will be "Test, XYZ". What am I doing wrong, that it gets concatenated and not written to the right attribute?

I have already tried to assign the object to a div but it didn't change anything

```html
<div th:object="${invoiceRecipientDTO}">
     <input type="text" class="form-control" id="fnameRecipient" data-item="fnameRecipient" th:field="*{fname}" required>
</div>
<div th:object="${guestDTO}">
     <input type="text" class="form-control" id="fnameGuest" data-item="fnameGuest" th:field="*{fname}" required>
</div>
```

I have also tried to work with th:value and assigning a name but it also didn't work

```html
<input type="text" class="form-control" id="fnameRecipient" data-item="fnameRecipient" name="fname" th:value="${invoiceRecipientDTO.fname}" required>

<input type="text" class="form-control" id="fnameGuest" data-item="fnameGuest" name="fname" th:value="${guestDTO.fname}" required>
```

In both cases the value of both input fields will be concatenated and assigned to fname.

My code right now:

Controller:

```java
    @GetMapping(CREATEBOOKING_URL)
    public String createBooking(Model model) {
        InvoiceRecipientDTO invoiceRecipientDTO = InvoiceRecipientDTO.create().setId("").build();
        GuestDTO guestDTO = GuestDTO.create().setId("").build();
        model.addAttribute("guestDTO", guestDTO);
        model.addAttribute("invoiceRecipientDTO", invoiceRecipientDTO);
        return CREATEBOOKING_VIEW;
    }



    @PostMapping(BOOKINGCONFIRMATION_URL)
    public ModelAndView summaryPage(InvoiceRecipientDTO invoiceRecipientDTO, GuestDTO guestDTO) {
        GuestTypeID guestTypeID = this.guestTypeService.createGuest(guestDTO.fname(), guestDTO.lname(), guestAddressDTO);
        InvoiceRecipientID invoiceRecipientID = this.invoiceRecipientService.createInvoiceRecipient(invoiceRecipientDTO.fname(), invoiceRecipientDTO.lname(), invoiceRecipientAddressDTO, invoiceRecipientDTO.phoneNumber(), invoiceRecipientDTO.email());
        this.invoiceRecipientService.assignBooking(bookingID.id(), invoiceRecipientID.id());
        this.invoiceRecipientService.assignGuestType(guestTypeID.id(), invoiceRecipientID.id());
        this.guestTypeService.assignInvoiceRecipient(guestTypeID.id(), invoiceRecipientID.id());
        return new ModelAndView();
    }
```

View:

```html
<form method="POST" th:action="@{/booking/bookingoverview}">
   <div class="form-row">
      <div class="form-guestGroup col-md-6">
            <label class="input_field_label" for="fnameRecipient">First Name</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="fnameRecipient" data-item="fnameRecipient" th:field="${invoiceRecipientDTO.fname}" required>
      </div>
   </div>    


   <div class="form-row">
        <div class="form-guestGroup col-md-6">
             <label class="input_field_label" for="fnameGuest">First Name (Guest)</label>
             <input type="text" class="form-control" data-item="fnameGuest" id="fnameGuest" th:field="${guestDTO.fname}">
        </div>
   </div>
<button type="submit" value="submit">Create Booking</button>
</form>
```

DTOs:

```java
public class InvoiceRecipientDTO {
    private String id;
    private String fname;
    private String lname;

    //getter and setter..
}

public class GuestDTO {
    private String id;
    private String fname;
    private String lname;

    //getter and setter..
}
```

When I change the attribute names of the objects (so that they are not identical anymore) it works but I don't want to change the attribute names. Aren't there any other solutions?

Comment: That's just how html works.  If you use the same name on a field, it appends the values like that.  If you want to pass multiple objects with same name attributes, you need to create a parent object that has both of the other objects as properties. Like this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/61594586/4126893

Comment: I just tried it out but I am getting following error: "Invalid property 'invoice' of bean class: Bean property 'invoice' is not readable or has an invalid getter method." Actually my variable is called **private InvoiceRecipientDTO invoice** and the getter is called **public InvoiceRecipientDTO invoice()**. Is the getter wrong?

Comment: Getters and setters should match the java bean standard -- if you are using the Thymeleaf `object.invoice` they should be `getInvoice()` and `setInvoice()`.

Comment: It worked I was trying to fix it the whole day :) Is there a possibility to not name the getter "getInvoice" because we have some programming guidelines and we have to name our getter like our attributes. For example when the attribute is called invoice the getter should be called invoice() too?

Comment: Those programming guidelines would appear to be in direct conflict with the JavaBeans naming & usage conventions. Frameworks such as Thymeleaf (and many others) rely on these conventions to allow dynamic location and execution of getters/setters (and more, besides). More info [here](https://docstore.mik.ua/orelly/java-ent/jnut/ch06_02.htm).

Comment: Well, thank you for your answer. I will ask the teacher if it is ok in this case.

Comment: If it's a hard "no", then you can use the getter name explicitly. So, for a field called `foo`, with a getter called  `foo()` instead of `getFoo()`, you can use expressions such as `th:text="{myObject.foo()}"`.